# Formatting the SQL-like script

Tags: formatting, sourcecode

Suppose we have a script as follows:

```
a = LOAD 'data' USING BinStorage AS (user);
b = GROUP a BY user;
c = FOREACH b GENERATE COUNT(a) AS cnt;
d = ORDER c BY cnt;
```

How to write the latex code to achieve the following effect:
[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{minted}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe that a simple `verbatim` environment will suffice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
a = LOAD `data' USING BinStorage AS (user);
b = GROUP a BY user;
c = FOREACH b GENERATE COUNT(a) AS cnt;
d = ORDER c BY cnt;
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Notice that we have to use the left single quote `` ` `` and right single quote `'` characters marks to get the right quotation marks.

Comment: The text flows out of the page, how do we wrap text here?

Answer (score 24):

I would leave it to `listings` package which understands SQL among many many other languages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\lstset{upquote=true}

\begin{document}
Here is an example 
\begin{lstlisting}[
           language=SQL,
           showspaces=false,
           basicstyle=\ttfamily,
           numbers=left,
           numberstyle=\tiny,
           commentstyle=\color{gray}
        ]
a = LOAD 'data' USING BinStorage AS (user);
b = GROUP a BY user;
/* Now we are ready to loop */
c = FOREACH b GENERATE COUNT(a) AS cnt;
d = ORDER c BY cnt;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does listing provide a way to "correct" the quote.

Comment: @Aditya Now fixed

Answer (score 5):

**Two** easy ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

For example:

{\obeylines\obeyspaces
\texttt{
a = LOAD 'data' USING BinStorage AS (user);
b = GROUP a BY user;
c = FOREACH b GENERATE COUNT(a) AS cnt;
d = ORDER c BY cnt;
}}

\medskip
Or:

\begin{verbatim}
a = LOAD 'data' USING BinStorage AS (user);
b = GROUP a BY user;
c = FOREACH b GENERATE COUNT(a) AS cnt;
d = ORDER c BY cnt;
\end{verbatim}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't remember -- does `\texttt` take `\par` tokens? It might be better in this case to use `\ttfamily`.

Answer (score 4):

Little typing practice:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% \usepackage{listings} you can use this also see the manual
%\usepackage[scaled=.9]{beramono}
\begin{document}
Another case where Pig is able to know the type of a field even when the program has not declared types is when operators or user-defined functions (UDFs) have been applied whose return type is known. In the following example Pig will order the output data numerically since it knows that the return type of \texttt{COUNT} is \verb|long|.
\begin{verbatim}
a = LOAD `data' USING BinStorage AS (user);
b = GROUP a BY user;
c = FOREACH b GENERATE COUNT(a) AS cnt;
d = ORDER c BY cnt;
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You just beat me to it! I should add that you need to use the left single quote `\`` and right single quote `'` characters to get the quotes "right".

Comment: @ILiketoCode I simply copy pasted :-)

Comment: Obligatory [rant](http://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2009/05/15/quote-backtick-and-unicode-engine/) whenever I see wrong quotes typeset by TeX. Please use a unicode engine (xetex or luatex), load the fontspec package and a unicode teletype font.